# Sprint report burndown chart showing only 1 hour for 2 week period

Tags: jira-agile

Trying to fix our sprint reports - we're using Jira v8.20.1. We converted from using other tools to using Atlassian Jira and basic Agile in December. I've been tromping through everything that I can find to figure out how to fix this and coming up with nothing.

The sprint reports for the first 7 sprints have a "good" burndown chart, meaning that we see the actual progress through the sprint. The y axis goes from the 240 hours we had as a team down to 0.

Beginning in sprint 8 (and we're now in 13), a new person took over creating the sprints and I think it was something in that switch that's causing problems. The y axis only has 1 hour on it, and the only graphic is a horizontal red line.

I'm trying to pin down what is different between how the first person created the sprints and the second person. Both are still with the company but not available right now. I don't know if it's missing info or a setting or something else entirely.

Here is an attempt to show the chart from the last "good" sprint report (sprint 7) and the first "bad" sprint report (sprint 8). I've never tried to embed in a SO post before.

[Sprint 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMLzN.png)

[Sprint 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwHK9.png)

Comment: When you create the sprint there is an option to enter the start date/time and the end date/time. If these have been set incorrectly it could explain the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but the start date/time and end date/time appear to be set correctly, so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: How does the burndown look on the burndown chart? Note that this is not the same as the sprint report and I have seen instances where the burndown looks fine on the burndown chart but broken on the sprint report.

Comment: Here's an example: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Sprint-report-shows-flat-line/qaq-p/1314575

Comment: Even worse, that's why I asked my question with the context being the sprint report. For all sprints, the charts are solid red lines with the y axis going from -1.0 up to 1.0. What I think is happening is that no one is logging work hours for each story. If you log hours, then the charts appear to be picking that up. I'm going to try backfilling hours on 1 of the sprints and see what happens. It just perplexes me that there was such a difference in the sprint reports between when person A and person B (neither of which is me.)

Comment: Perhaps person B altered the configuration or encouraged the team to try a different time reporting approach? The only other thing I can think of is that the change of person was a coincidence and that a Jira update might have caused the problem.